# How to batch-rename files in multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch-rename

I run windows 10, and want to rename a single file `a.jpg` to `b.jpg` in many folders. Is possible?

Comment: Use something like `FORFILES /P x:\folder /M a.jpg /S /C "move @path b.jpg"`